# generate variable based on first occurrence of a value

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have 5 repeat measures called `pub1:pub5` each taking a value of 1 to 4. Each was measured at a different age `age1:age5`. That is, `pub1` was measured at `age1`....`pub5` at `age5` etc.

I would like to create a new variable `age_pb2` that shows the age at which a value of 2 first occurred in `pub`. For example, for individual x, `age_pb2` will equal `age3` if the first time a value of 2 is scored is in `pub3`

I have tried modifying previous code but not had much luck.

```
library(tidyverse)
#Example data
N <- 2000
data <- data.frame(id = 1:2000,age1 = rnorm(N,6:8),age2 = rnorm(N,7:9),age3 = rnorm(N,8:10),
               age4 = rnorm(N,9:11),age5 = rnorm(N,10:12),pub1 = rnorm(N,1:2),pub2 = rnorm(N,1:2),
               pub3 = rnorm(N,1:2),pub4 = rnorm(N,1:2),pub5 = rnorm(N,1:2))

 data <- data %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("pub")), funs(round(replace(., .< 0, NA), 0)))

#New variable showing first age at getting a score of 2 (doesn't work)

i1 <- grepl('^pub', names(data)) # index for pub columns
i2 <- grepl('^age', names(data)) # index for age columns

data[paste0("age_pb2")] <- lapply(2, function(i) {
j1 <- max.col(data[i1] == i, 'first')
j2 <- rowSums(data[i1] == i) == 0
data[i2][cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), j1 *(NA^j2))]
})
```

Comment: Please post  `dput(data)`

Comment: Thanks, I've added example data, just looking to identify the age at which first observe a value of 2 in any of the pub variables

Comment: Your wanted output is vector of numbers 1:5 corresponding to pub (length of data) or those age values?

Comment: My output should correspond to the age values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 2000
data <- data.frame(id = 1:2000,age1 = rnorm(N,6:8),age2 = rnorm(N,7:9),age3 = rnorm(N,8:10),
                   age4 = rnorm(N,9:11),age5 = rnorm(N,10:12),pub1 = rnorm(N,1:2),pub2 = rnorm(N,1:2),
                   pub3 = rnorm(N,1:2),pub4 = rnorm(N,1:2),pub5 = rnorm(N,1:2)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("pub")), funs(round(replace(., .< 0, NA), 0))) %>%
  mutate(age_pb2 = eval(parse(text = paste0("age", which.min(apply(select(., starts_with("pub")), 2, function(x) which(x == 2)[1]))))))
```

The way it works, you `apply` over the pubs columns and take with `which(x == 2)[1]` the first matched row per column, then take the `which.min` to get the column index number (of pub respectively age) which you then `paste` with "age" to assign (using `eval(parse(text = variable name))`) the respective column.

E.g. here after `apply` you get

```
[pub1 = 2,  pub2 = 1, pub3 = 2, pub4 = 4, pub5 = 2]
```

which is the first occurrence of 2 per column. The earliest (`which.min`) occurrence is for the second pub column, thus index is `2`. This pasted with "age" and eval parsed to mutate.

**EDIT**

It is probably more convenient to do it in a for loop for all age_pbi, or there is an easy solution in `dplyr` that I am not aware of.

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  index <- which.min(apply(select(data, starts_with("pub")), 2, function(x) which(x == i)[1]))
  data[ ,paste0("age_pb", i)] <- data[ ,paste0("age", index)]
}
```

*Note however, that `which.min` takes the first minimum. E.g. pub1 and pub2 both have a 1 in the first row, so the above approach assigns age1 to age_pb1 whereas it could be age2 as well. I don't know what you want to do with this, so can't say what is a better option.*